# input type="number", в alert value выводит пустоту когда я пишу 1- или 1-1

Tags: javascript, input, value

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, что мне нужно было, чтобы не вводился минус. Причем не только с клавы но и другими способами. Проблему я решил на половину. Дело в том что я смог сделать, чтобы минус не мог появляться самым первым в input и вроде бы решил 2ую часть проблемы с минусом в других частях числа. Но у меня перестала вводится точка.

```
<input type="number" id="bet">

var inputBet = document.getElementById("bet");

inputBet.oninput = function() {
  //Запрещаем минус в input любыми способами(ctrl + v, перетаскивание мышкой и.т.д)
  //В начале input
  if (inputBet.value < 0) {
    inputBet.value = inputBet.value / -1;
  //В других местах
  } else if (inputBet.value == "") {
    inputBet.value = "";
  }
}
```

Как решить проблему, чтобы минусов вообще не могло быть в input, а точки не затрагивались, при этом оставляя type="number"

Comment: Правильно выводит. Ограничительный механизм не допускает попаденя в данный вид контрола недопустимых значений (кроме случая предустановки), хоть это значение визуально присутствует - реально его там (в свойстве контрола value) нет и не будет. Или делаете валидацию вручную, или получаете такой эффект, если используете встроеный валидатор.

Comment: можете привести пример валидации для данной проблемы?

Comment: В зависимости от задачи - вариант 1 - ставите `type=number`  удаляете oninput обработчик, и довольствуетесь встроеным валидатором. Можно дополнить pattern/min/max/required атрибутами. Вариант 2 - удаляете  `type=number` что б не мешал встроеный валидатор  и пишите в oninput валидатор такой какой нравится - тогда не будет глюка.

Comment: Хорошо, попробую. Спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все, решение нашлось. nick_n_a спасибо за наводку.

```
inputBet.oninput = function() {
  //Запрещаем все кроме цифр и точки любыми способами(ctrl + v, перетаскивание мышкой и.т.д)
  inputBet.value = inputBet.value.replace(/[^\d.]*/g, '')
    .replace(/([,.])[,.]+/g, '$1')
    .replace(/^[^\d]*(\d+([.,]\d{0,5})?).*$/g, '$1');
}
```